# target class nurse controller does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

[image]

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\NuserController;

Route::resource('user',NuserController::class);
```

Comment: change your code to this: `Route::resource('user','NuserController');`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In laravel 8 route folder in web.php file add controller
namespace like this

```php
<?php 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\NuserController;

Route::resource('user',NuserController::class); // using resource`
Route::get('/user',[NuserController::class,'index']);  // normal controller index method call`
```

Comment: How's this different from your question? And what are you trying to do here in the answer? Is your issue resolved - how?